# YouTube app won't display the same search results as the desktop version

Tags: youtube

The main problem I've been having is that searching for "Stairway to Heaven" and a few other songs on the app returns only covers, live performances, etc; Only when I search on my laptop do I get the actual song. Is there any way to get past this issue?

I'm using an Xperia Miro ICS 4.0, and the default YouTube app.

Answer (score 1):

Some videos on YouTube are not available to mobile devices. This restriction applies via the website (when accessed through a mobile device) as well as the YouTube app. This happens when someone has filed a "copyright claim" against a video (that is, they believe the video infringes their copyright, or "Content ID" matched the video against some copyrighted content, most likely the latter given that you're searching for a commercial music recording), and the alleged copyright-holder has told YouTube to allow their content to be used on desktops but not on mobile.

Even if it's possible to work around this, it would probably be illegal for us to make this information available to US citizens, because that's circumventing a technological restriction under the meaning of the DMCA. This applies regardless of whether the copyright claim is well-founded.

You can get the actual song by buying a recording of it, or by downloading it through some music-pirating service.

Comment: well I'm european is it illegal if I explain how do to it ?

Comment: @Kiwy It's a crime in the US wherever you do it. US police have been known to arrest people on entry to the US for offences under the DMCA committed by foreigners outside the US, e.g. Dmitri Skylarov.